# How to get JSON data from adding mulitple marker in Google map

Tags: android

Here is my code , my question is how we save json object of particualr marker.I have already get data from service and save all data in v_data ArrayList. Also how we get in InfoWindow ?

```
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);


            for (int i = 0; i< v_data.size(); i++){
               try {
                   if(!v_data.get(i).getString("latitude").equalsIgnoreCase("") && !v_data.get(i).getString("longitude").equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                       double latitude =  Double.parseDouble(v_data.get(i).getString("latitude"));
                       double longitude =  Double.parseDouble(v_data.get(i).getString("longitude"));
                       MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
                       marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.dollar_one_map_icon));

                       lat = latitude;
                       longt = longitude;
                       Marker mrk = googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                       mrk.showInfoWindow();

                   }

               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
```

Comment: theres a tutorial here -- http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html

Comment: just create a list for storing latitude and longitude and then iterate over the list and add using MarkerOptions.

Comment: Thanks for this info . @ Tasos  and @Gautam